# Is the term 'Invalid' applicable for human beings?

Tags: nouns

As I was reading a novel 'What Katy Did', I came across an interesting mention of the word *Invalid.*

> His wife was said to be an invalid, and people, when they spoke of him, shook their heads and wondered how the poor woman got on all alone in the house, while her husband was absent.

For me, it sounds off. Can invalid be a valid word for human beings?

I have heard about things like - the credit card is invalid, the transaction is invalid, your registration is invalid..., but how about your husband is invalid?

Comment: Maulik's answer is certainly correct, but the pronunciation difference is important so make sure you check out Chenmunka's answer as well.

Comment: I strongly suggest reading FumbleFinger's answer.  It provides the most accurate and relevant information, with the more important details provided.  Maulik's answer doesn't particularly detail out what an invalid is beyond being sick (it's not that simple).  Chenmunka's answer also doesn't provide too much detail and what it does provide is potentially confusing and could lead to insult if a learner used 'invalid' to describe a person with just any disability (a person in a wheelchair, blind, etc is not an invalid, even though they are disabled/handicapped).

Comment: @Doc You can even add too much detail by go on explaining the etymology, justification of whether it should be PC/NONPC and so on. But The OP here **simply** asked, what **invalid** means here and he seems unaware of the **basic definition**.  The basic question is *How a person can be invalid* (which I addressed it) and not *Is calling a person 'invalid' morally okay?'* (This I would have certainly explained thoroughly being a healthcare provider). And yes, I know this better than others because my mother is **invalid** since last year.

Comment: @MaulikV I have no comment regarding morality or PC, but calling a blind person an invalid simply isn't the proper use of the word.  Nor would a person with chronic back pain, Asthma, Diabetes, Epilepsy, HIV, etc - all of which are chronic illnesses that fall into your provided extremely oversimplified definition.  Most injuries, even extremely serious ones that lead to amputation of multiple limbs would also not make a person an invalid (except maybe temporarily during early recovery).  **Those** details are important to understanding the **basic definition**.

Comment: The film Gattaca uses the term in the nonconventional sense of "this person is not valid".  I haven't seen it used this way anywhere else.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*invalid* there is a noun.

> [invalid (n)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/INVALID) - *Someone who is incapacitated by a chronic illness or injury.*

Having this said, his wife seems to be very sick, in a crucial condition that might have made her *incapacitated.*

Now since there's discussion about the *degree* of being incapacitated (which makes you ultimately invalid), I'm adding a bit to improve this answer.

Here is another reference from OLD:

> [invalid (n)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/invalid-2) - a person who needs other people to take care of them, because of illness that they have had for a long time.

Now, if you look at both the definitions, you see that the term *invalid* ranges from someone being assisted by others to walk, eat or do routine activity **to** someone who is permanently bedridden (as in the last stage of cancers). Contrary to what Doc and FumbleFingers, it is **not** always necessary that *invalid* person is so so so sick that he/she is on the deathbed. And, I'm a doctor and have come across *many* such patients with chronic illness (in fact, have worked in hospitals that **only** take such cases).

The OLD further explains it in its example:

> She had been a delicate child and her parents had treated her as an *invalid*

Furthermore, delicate here means:

> [delicate (n)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/delicate) - (of a person) not strong and easily becoming sick

That's where the WordWeb definition fits in. Invalid is someone who is *incapacitated* - not able to perform their tasks because of illness that has brought weakness. Here, the child does not necessary to have *Ryley's tube or Folly's catheter* as *Doc* mentions.

On the other hand, invalid *does not always mean* that the person is just incapable to do things and is not so critical. **That's why I said,** the term applies to *incapacitation* and this **varies from degree to degree** depending on the illness that person has.

Check this here:

[image]

If you see *Saturnino Soncko* (a person working in the silver mines of Cerro Rico), he's certainly invalid **but** I can still argue and deny calling him *invalid* as at least he is not that incapacitated! In that picture at least he is **sitting without any assistance** whereas *invalid* requires support even for this, don't they? **They certainly do** I see the woman every day. She is an invalid and cannot move anything other than her eyes.

Again, *invalid* is certainly a serious condition but it varies in degrees or severity depending upon the type of illness. I'm not sure to apply *partially invalid* or *completely invalid* for that though it might make better sense.

Comment: Typically, to be an invalid, the person must be so ill that they are bedridden and unable to do much of anything themselves.  They must be fed, they may need the use of a bed-pan (basically a pan in the bed that they use to urinate in), etc.  Being blind, or missing a limb or such would not cause you to be an invalid, as you can still do stuff yourself.

Comment: @Alium Britt what about too bad, too pathetic and other such negative words? Tea is too hot to drink and tea is very hot to drink -both means you cannot drink it now but have a bit difference in meaning. In fact, I intentionally put *too* to bring in more seriousness. Anyway, already approved by WendiKid so let it be.

Comment: I never suggested *invalid* implies someone is so ill they're "on their deathbed", and I doubt @Doc thinks that either. As he says, *invalid* is normally used of people who are unable to care for themselves properly - usually caused by chronic illness, often leading to the person being bedridden, but not particularly associated with imminent death.

Comment: the french spelling "Invalide" is sometimes used in English to clearly disambiguate and to indicate the alternative pronunciation.

Comment: Like @FumbleFingers said, I don't mean to imply that an invalid is on their deathbed, or even that they are incapable of all things, but that they are unable to care for themselves in many 'basic' ways.  Perhaps they need to be fed because they are unable to walk to the kitchen and cook their own food (so must have someone else cook it and bring it to them, perhaps even spooning it into their mouths, nasogastric intubation unnecessary).  Maybe they require spongebaths because they can't take a traditional shower/bath.  Maybe they can't walk to the toilet, and so need a bed pan.  Etc.

Comment: @MaulikV - When you use those other negative words, you also need to know what it is that you're exceeding. Sometimes it's obvious from context and then you don't have to directly say it, but you still need to know. The phrase "The tea is very hot to drink" is incorrect, but notice that in this sentence with "too" you're stating what is being exceeded, and that is the drinking temperature for tea. You can't say "too sick" without saying, for example "to stand up" or "to take care of herself". "Too" by itself doesn't simply mean a stronger version of "very".

Answer (score 33):

An invalid, pronounced with stress on the first syllable, is a person with a disability.  The word is not used so often nowadays.

It is a noun and a different word to the adjective invalid, pronounced with stress on the second syllable, which means not valid.

So the last sentence of your question "Your husband is invalid" is incorrect, it would be "Your husband is an invalid".

Comment: As a side note, Invalid is quite common in the german language as an synonym for handicapped...

Comment: +1 but I disagree that using invalid as a noun is uncommon or not pc; it is relatively common and the word itself is perfectly polite (although of course pointing out that someone is an invalid is socially delicate).

Comment: @hunter; I don't find it non-PC either.  However, I know some disabled people who do.  Hence my use of "some people".  As ever, political correctness is a murky area.

Comment: @Chenmunka: I've no doubt many *disabled people* would object to being called *invalids*, but I don't really think that's because the term itself is "non-PC". It's just ***the wrong word*** for people who happen to have a disability (blind, missing a limb, etc.).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Just my opinion, but, if any people are offend by the term, then it falls under the "non-PC" umbrella. I'd have to research it, but I'd be surprised if there were no people out there who were bothered by this term, whether it was being applied to them, or someone else.

Comment: @J.R.: As referenced in my own answer, we did use the term *invalid car/carriage*, and that has definitely fallen out of favour. But in general *invalid = disabled* has never had any significant currency - so people will quite rightly object because it's ***idiomatically non-standard***, not because it's non-PC.

Comment: @J.R. I see your point, but is that perhaps not a little far? I think every word in the English language would be non-PC if it became so if it offended anyone whatsoever? I am sure there is for just about any word somebody who will find it offensive.

Comment: @user5842: yes, that is the danger with the "political correctness" movement.  This has to do with evaluating the underlying meanings of words and coming up with ones that are less negative or judgmental for the same.  Of course, the assessment that a word is judgmental is an exercise in *being* judgmental, so there are issues in that as well.  "Invalid" was commonly in use when I was a child.  The change to the more common "disabled" over that time avoids the connotation "not a valid person" that the term invalid implies.

Comment: @user5482 - What Bob said. Also, I suppose there would need to be more than one or two individuals who got offended by a term. I was just trying to say that whether or not something is "non-PC" fluctuates depending who decides in their own mind that something should be offensive. A word might be fine this year but cause people to bristle next year. It's often fuzzy, and sometimes ridiculous.

Comment: @BobRodes: I'm obviously in the minority here on ELL, but so far as I'm concerned this answer is hopelessly misleading, in that it starts off by saying *"an **invalid** is a person with a **disability**"*. But to most people, an invalid is a (usually, *old*, frequently *bed-ridden*) person enfeebled by ***chronic illness/poor health***. Obviously many disabled people are perfectly fit (apart from their specific disability), so they wouldn't take kindly to being given that label by people who don't have a very firm grasp of how such terms are normally used.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: FWIW I agree. I'm not sure it's *hopelessly* misleading. It's true that an invalid has a disability of some kind (at least, I think a chronic debilitating illness could be called a form of disability), but it's not true that's what invalid *means*. The meaning of "an invalid" is closer to "incapacitated" than "disabled". It's also context-sensitive, for soldiers to be "invalided out" just meant they could no longer serve, so this did cover a wide range of injuries that might be called "disability" but wouldn't make them "an invalid" in civilian life.

Comment: @Steve: Per my own answer, there are specific usages where the meanings of *invalid* and *disabled* effectively overlap, but in general they don't much. I'd also point out that this answer currently makes no mention of adjectival *invalid = in poor health* - if you didn't already know about that, you'd probably be left with the impression there's only ***noun** = disabled person* and ***adjective** = not valid*, distinguished by whether the stress falls on the first or second syllable. *And* it incorrectly claims *the word is not used so often nowadays*. I stand by *hopelessly* misleading.

Comment: I actually think I would laugh fairly heartily if I heard a woman intentionally say, "My husband is invalid."  Because it would be awesome.

Comment: Definitions of "invalid" taken from the online dictionaries: suffering from disease or disability; one who is sickly or disabled; to remove from active duty by reason of sickness or disability; to make sickly or disabled; One who is incapacitated by a chronic illness or disability; a person suffering from disablement or chronic ill health; an infirm or sickly person, esp. one who is too sick or weak to care for himself or herself. Of these, the last one is the only one that doesn't mention disability in the definition.

Comment: Now, I might agree that the concept of "invalid" in most people's minds makes the person seem less capable of taking care of him/herself than "disabled". This may well be for the reasons I've stated, and it may not. It may, in fact, be one of the triumphs of the PC movement, loath as I may be to say so. However, I do not find that the statement "an invalid is a person with a disability" is misleading, hopelessly or otherwise. I may also say that I believe I have backed up my POV pretty well. :)

Comment: There's an old story about the customer who call up a computer company to complain that his computer was prejudiced. Whatever he typed, it responded with "invalid input not accepted", and he was furious that it wouldn't work for him just because he had a bad back... Yes, "invalid" is the correct spelling of two related but very different words.

Comment: I think in [Gattaca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gattaca) they called people in-val-ids (non-eugenic children who are "genetically disabled") rather than in-va-lids.

Answer (score 21):

The most common usage (adjectival ***invalid = not valid***) has stress on the *second* syllable. In principle this sense could occur as a noun *("We sorted the ballot papers into valids and invalids")*, but this would be considered creative/non-standard usage.

---

But there's also adjectival ***invalid = in poor health***, where the stress falls on the *first* syllable. As per OP's example, this is also often used as a noun - *[**an**] invalid = [a person] in poor health*.

It's not in the least a "politically incorrect" term. Anyone who thinks that may be  mistakenly conflating it with ***handicapped = affected with a physical or mental disability*** (which *is* often considered offensive today, and tends to be replaced by ***disabled***).

It's also worth pointing out that the term ***invalid car*** (aka [*invalid carriage*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invalid_carriage)) probably *does* have negative connotations. But that's mainly because (in the UK, at least) they were often seen as cheap, unsafe, and demeaning (for several decades, the [UK motability scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motability) has provided disabled people with specially-modified versions of standard cars where practicable).

---

As the NGrams for [*my **invalid** mother*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my%20invalid%20mother&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,my%20invalid%20mother;,c0) and [*mother is an **invalid***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mother%20is%20an%20invalid&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,mother%20is%20an%20invalid;,c0) show, usage has remained fairly constant over the past half-century. We don't often use the adjectival form *my mother is **invalid***, but this is simply a matter of idiomatic preference, not "grammar".

The *poor health* sense also occurs (relatively rarely) as a verb meaning *cause to be/treat as an invalid* - often in passive constructions including a "destination", such as *the patient was invalided home, the soldier was invalided out [of the war]*.

As Maulik's answer indicates, *invalid* carries the sense of *infirm, enfeebled, or disabled as a result of chronic illness or injury*. Political correctness aside, there's no clear-cut distinction between the two - but in general, ***invalid*** is more strongly associated with ***illness***/health problems arising later in life, whereas ***handicapped*** is far more likely to be used in respect of [***congenital*** disorders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congenital_disorder) (birth defects).

Comment: What makes anything politically incorrect is simply that a bunch of people think so, not necessarily for any, ahem, valid reason.

Comment: @Kaz: I don't disagree. But I only posted my answer in the first place because the (still) top-rated answer claimed the *invalid = infirm* usage was "non-PC". And although it's now been edited out, it does seem that at least *some* people think there's some truth to this idea. But really, [invalid cars](http://i616.photobucket.com/albums/tt244/ak1023/acinvalid.jpg) got a bad press because they were rubbish *cars*, not because it was a bad *word*. Again, UK *Incapacity Benefit* replaced *Invalidity Benefit* because it was a *different* scheme, not because the old name was somehow "offensive".

Comment: This seems to be the best answer.  Handicapped/disabled are not the same thing as an invalid.  Typically, to be an invalid, the person must be so ill that they are bedridden and unable to do much of anything themselves. They may need to be fed, they may need the use of a bed-pan (basically a pan in the bed that they use to urinate in), etc. Being blind, or missing a limb or such would not cause you to be an invalid, as you can still do stuff yourself.

Comment: @Doc: You're absolutely right that in general, *invalids* are more "ill" (and less able to live independently) than people who are classed as *disabled, handicapped*. I've made that point myself in other comments, but I realise now I didn't explicitly mention it in my answer text. I kinda think one of the drawbacks of ELL is that many if not most people casting votes aren't actually native speakers, so there are twice as many upvotes here for an answer that says *an invalid ... is a person with a disability* (among other errors). Or maybe people just like "voting for the underdog"! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, I noticed you had mentioned it in other comments, but if this ends up getting top voted eventually felt it'd be important to have it here too =P  Also, completely agree with thoughts about votes.  Same goes for the accepted answer which only provides a (very short) definition and "the wife seems to be sick" - not very useful to a learner...

Comment: @FumbleFingers *voting for the underdog* is not a polite comment. They are the ones who have voted for you as well :)

Comment: @Maulik: I haven't checked your recent (extensive) edit, but I'd upvoted your original answer before posting my own (although yours was short, it seemed accurate so far as it went). My problem is with Chenmunka's answer - which I still think is *not* correct, and which is what prompted me to post an answer myself.

Comment: @MaulikV Like FumbleFingers, I also upvoted your original answer, and simply left a comment to add a level of clarification for any readers.  I also upvoted this answer.

Comment: +1 Good answer. However, at least in the U.S., the word 'handicapped' is used more generically than what is suggested here. It's used just as commonly to refer to people who are disabled due to old age or injury as it used to refer to those with congenital disorders. It does more commonly refer to situations where the condition is permanent, but even that isn't a requirement.

Comment: @reirrab: I didn't know that US/UK distinction until now. I've just found [*I am American and the accepted term in the US is **handicapped**. **Disabled** is not PC*](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/legacy/pm/2007/06/is_handicapped_offensive.shtml). If that's generally true then AmE sensitivities are a complete *reversal* of BrE. As that poster implies, the distinction seems to be completely arbitrary. I wonder which (if either) will eventually become the global standard for Anglophones.

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of French in English. If you ever get to Paris, there is a very famous place called [Les Invalides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Invalides) and the reason it is called that is because it has a military hospital on the site. The invalids in question being war wounded. Oh, and Napoleon is buried there in the midst of the invalids because to be an invalid was very honourable indeed. So while you see the term as demeaning or even shocking, others see it quite differently.

But the term also applies to civilians.

Today as you go around France, you might be baffled to see parking spaces or train seats reserved for G.I.G. and G.I.C. In both cases the 'I' means *invalides*.

G.I.G. *grands invalides de guerre* (badly injured veterans i.e. impaired mobility)

G.I.C. *grands invalides civils* (badly injured civilians, see above)

English can be very mealy-mouthed viz the movement from *invalid* to *incapacitated* to *handicapped* to *disabled* to *mobility challenged*.

Answer (score 4):

In Russian language, 'invalid' term is applicable exactly to human beings and means the disabled human. I suppose it might be so in another languages, so there's question if the mentioned book was translated to English from another language.

Similar in general, but different in particularities meanings are typical for the words borrowed from another languages

F.ex.... 'hund' means 'a dog' in Norwegian, but 'hound' means the kind of dog in English

'Speculation' means something like pondering, contemplation, thinking in English, but in Russian it means only the buying something cheaper and sell expensive thus making the profit (it was reason to be jailed in Soviet times BTW :) ).

Origin is obviously the same but the usage survived for one particular meaning.

So for the word 'sympathy' has nothing common in its Russian analog with  condolence, compassion - it means only something like attraction, appeal, affection.

And many another words which are borrowed tend to mutate in another languages acquiring slightly deviated meaning. Sometimes in the translated messages I noticed the misusing of such words when the interpreter translated it from English literally and it sounded off in Russian. I guess it might be a case for the discussed example as well.